# Easier way to clean up text

Tags: python

I'm currently using a rather convoluted way to clean up text in my dataset by removing stop words and weird characters. Is there a more out of the box way to achieve this?

By clean up, I mean replace bad symbols, slashes, @, etc. so that it only contains characters that are present in word2vec models. I'm also removing English stop words. Put the entire text in lower case, remove html tags, etc., as per below:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
# !pip install lxml
import lxml

REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;]')
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def clean_text(text):
    """
        text: a string

        return: modified initial string
    """
#     text = BeautifulSoup(text, features="xml").text
    text = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser').text # HTML decoding
    text = text.lower() # lowercase text
    text = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(' ', text) # replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text
    text = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub('', text) # delete symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text
    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in STOPWORDS) # delete stopwors from text
    return text
```

Comment: Define "clean up". Clean up how? What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: @deceze I have updated the question to reflect what clean text means.

Comment: "so that it only contains characters that are present in word2vec models".  I think this is the key thing here.  Couldn't you make a dictionary of acceptable words based on a model you're interested in and then filter out anything that isn't in the dictionary?  Membership testing should be fast enough.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're doing.   Why do you have `a-z` in `BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')`?